# SQL Newbie: Use a foreign key for a lookup table being used like an enum() field?

Tags: sql, foreign-key-relationship

Say I have field Ice_Cream.flavor, with the current choices in lookup table Flavor.flavor.

I use Flavor.flavor like an enum() list, storing the **value**, **not** the record ID, in Ice_Cream.flavor. If Flavor.flavor changes, I don't want to update Ice_Cream:flavor. I want it to stay as created.

Should I set up Ice_Cream.Flavor as a foreign key, so I can see the source of the values in my ER diagram, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `Ice_Cream.flavor` to stay as created even if there is *no matching record in `Flavor`* (which is what your question sounds like) then you *cannot* create a `FOREIGN KEY` relationship, it will not allow that condition to occur in your database.

Furthermore, if you're storing the actual text `Flavor.Flavor` string in `Ice_Cream.Flavor`, there's no particular reason to have a separate `RecordID` column in `Flavor`.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you do not need a FK here except if you have additional informations about a flavor in the `Flavor` table beside the name in the column `flavor`. It is the case because you do not keep an ID, you keep the name **AND** you want to keep the old value.

I also supposed that you do not want to keep old flavors in the `Flavor` table or elsewhere except in the `Ice_Cream` table.

Last but not least, a FK would require that any flavor stored in `Ice_Cream.flavor` exists in the `Flavor` table.  It is not the case if I understand correctly your question.